# How to put randomly uniform dots within a set boundary?

Tags: python, gis

I am trying to put random dots I generated through the imports matplotlib and random.

I am able to generate the number of dots I need like this:

```
upper = 0 lower = 500

for points in range(upper, lower):
    rand_lat = random.uniform(upper, lower)
    rand_lng = random.uniform(upper, lower)
    plt.plot(rand_lat, rand_lng, 'bo')
```

When I run it here are the results:

[image]

After I've generated those points I want to contain them within set boundaries I made for the state. I have the longitude/latitudes set up from North, West, East, South as follows:

```
plt.plot( [-109.05,-102.05,-102.05,-109.05,-109.05], [41,41,37,37,41] )
```

But I need them to fit all inside a state boundary as set above. That state boundary looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have everything you need at hand already. Just do it like this:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

n = 1000

xlo, xhi = -109, -102
ylo, yhi = 37, 41

x_rand = [random.uniform(xlo, xhi) for _ in range(n)]
y_rand = [random.uniform(ylo, yhi) for _ in range(n)]

ax = plt.figure().gca()
ax.scatter(x_rand, y_rand, s=5)
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((xlo,ylo), abs(xlo-xhi), abs(yhi-ylo), linewidth=1, 
                               edgecolor='r', facecolor='none', linestyle='--'))
plt.show()
```

which gives you

[image]

---

From your comments I sense you're looking for something like this:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

w = 1
n = 100
quadrants = [(x, y) for x in range(-1, 1) for y in range(-1, 1)]

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8)).gca()

markers = ['x', '^', 'o', ',']

for marker, q in zip(markers, quadrants):

    xlo, ylo = q
    xhi, yhi = xlo+w, ylo+w

    x_rand = [random.uniform(xlo, xhi) for _ in range(n)]
    y_rand = [random.uniform(ylo, yhi) for _ in range(n)]

    ax.scatter(x_rand, y_rand, s=25, marker=marker)    
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((xlo,ylo), abs(xlo-xhi), abs(yhi-ylo), linewidth=1, 
                               edgecolor='k', facecolor='none', linestyle='--'))
```

[image]

Comment: This is an appropriate answer given that the "state" boundary is strictly rectangular, which is the only case that was requested. If the geometry changes the numbers will need to be generated differently.

Comment: Thank you! I am also trying to restrict it to specific quadrants with the middle longitude and latitude that seperates the quadrants being: (-105.50, 39).
What I have so far is:
Q1 = plt.plot( [-105.5,-102.05,-102.05,-105.5,-105.5] , [41,41,39,39,41] )
------------------------
Q2 = plt.plot( [-109.05,-105.5,-105.5,-109.05,-109.05] , [41,41,39,39,41] )

Comment: I think I figured that out. Would you mind checking my work on it:

plt.plot( [-109.05,-102.05,-102.05,-109.05,-109.05], [41,41,37,37,41] )


Q1 = plt.plot( [-105.5,-102.05,-102.05,-105.5,-105.5] , [41,41,39,39,41] )
-----------------------
Q2 = plt.plot( [-109.05,-105.5,-105.5,-109.05,-109.05] , [41,41,39,39,41] )
------------------------
Q3 = plt.plot( [-109.05,-109.05,-105.5,-105.5,-109.05] , [37,39,39,37,37] )
------------------------
Q4 = plt.plot( [-105.5,-105.5,-102.05,-102.05,-105.5] , [39,39,39,37,37] )

Comment: With those quads isolated how might I populate different shapes into just those regions?

Comment: @SoscratesFd Not quite sure if I understand but.. you always draw a rectangle based on two points `(xlo, ylo)` and `(xhi, yhi)` in our case. All you have to do is adjust those values and change the rectangle you want to draw samples from. Or what is the question here?

Comment: @Stefan Falk I have the rectangles I just need to populate each quadrant with a different symbol. Here is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/JzNNR

Comment: @StefanFalk now I just want to populate an original symbol for each quadrant. I tried using conditionals but all that is doing is putting diamonds like so: https://imgur.com/a/3ptgC

Comment: @SoscratesFd Well the simplest would be to set the `marker` parameter of the scatter function e.g. `marker='x'` or `marker='v'` etc.
 ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html))

Comment: @StefanFalk sort of relegated to just using the basics and matplotlib and random

Comment: @StefanFalk oh yeah! I see what you are saying. I thought that was a library.

Comment: @StefanFalk changed the code in that link. Now it's not printing any symbols but just the quadrants.

Comment: @SoscratesFd See my update. All you have to do now is make sure you get the correct values for the actual target boundaries.

Comment: @SoscratesFd You're welcome - glad to help. Btw you don't have to address the user if you're commenting on his post. The @ username is only necessary if you want to refer to a user which did not write the post.